# Add Due 2 day reminder, add due date reminder until Status is closed

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I have SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint Designer 2010. I am trying to create a workflow where a 2 day reminder email is sent before the actual due date and then an actual "Due Today" email when the due date is reached. Also, if the date is changed, I would like it to update the workflow. However, if this is not possible, I'd like for 5 days to be added when the due date is reached. I want the workflow to stop when the status is updated to "Closed" and send out an email stating it has been closed.

So far, I have the following:
[image]

If I could have a step-by-step instruction on how to achieve this, that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are:

1. Send the first notification email 2 days before Due Date.
2. Then, send second notification email on the Due Date.
3. If the Status is “Closed”, send the close email and stop the workflow.
4. If the Due Date or Status is changed, re-start the workflow.

For the above three requirements, you can refer to the following workflow actions. 
 [image]
 [image]

Start the workflow when an item is created and changed.

[image]

However for the forth requirement, if the workflow is in progress, it will not be terminated and be re-started automatically when an item is changed. As a workaround, you need to terminate the workflow programmatically using Event Receiver. Every time an item has been changed, check whether a workflow instance is still running. If so, terminate the running workflow and start a new one.

Demo about [how to terminate SharePoint list workflow using an event receiver](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f2e7881e-b14f-4de9-81ac-fecfa2391f0c/stop-workflow-if-field-changes?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Is it possible to instead when the due date is reached, 5 days are added to the date automatically and repeats the workflow with the 2 day reminder etc.?

Comment: Also, your workflow works great. Thank you. It seems that any time an item is updated, a workflow starts even when there is no date added to the Requested Due Date field. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You can add a condition before these actions. The blank date value is 1/1/0001. If the Requested Due Date is greater than 1/1/0001, it it not blank, then run the next actions.

Comment: It is difficult to loop actions in one workflow. An ideal is that, create  two identical workflows that trigger each other. One workflow changes the list item will trigger another workflow. Make sure the "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" is selected.